# trying to setup ava unit testing for a next.js project but getting two errors related to the setup

Tags: javascript, next.js, enzyme, ava

working through setting up ava testing within my package.json file. 
However when I try to run the test from the command line getting this

```
following error:
    throw new TypeError(`Expected \`moduleId\` to be of type \`string\`, got \`${typeof moduleId}\``);
```

edit: using ava version 1.0.0-beta.8"

package.json

```
   "ava": {
    "cache": false,
    "files": [
      "../test/**/*"
    ],
    "sources": [
      "../renderer/components/**/*.{js, jsx}"
    ],
    "concurrency": 5,
    "failFast": true,
    "require": [
      [
        "babel-register",
        "babel-polyfill"
      ],
      "ignore-styles",
      "./test/helpers/setup-browser-env.js"
    ],
    "babel": {
      "extensions": [
        "js",
        "jsx"
      ]
    }
  }
```

update:
using a .babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "stage-2",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "espower",
        "transform-runtime"
    ]
}
```

Currently trying to get ava to read from my .babelrc file

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared your AVA version, but it looks like it did find files to test it just couldn't compile them. Make sure you're using the latest version and perhaps the error message will be less ambiguous.

Looking at the screenshot AVA is choking on the JSX syntax in your test file. You can either make sure AVA applies the correct config in its Babel pipeline or disable it altogether, so you can rely on `babel-register`.

Give this a read: https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/babel.md

Answer (score 0):

through testing and working with my friend.
Figured out the error was related to the ava version.
https://github.com/avajs/ava/issues/1903

downgraded from latest to ava@1.0.0-beta.8 and then did a normal setup with babel and a .babelrc file which allowed me to run tests now.